# requirejs: How to name submodule foo.bar instead of foo/bar?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I can get a submodule `bar` of some package `foo` to be known to `requirejs` as `foo/bar`, but can I somehow get it to use the name `foo.bar` instead?  (This is consistent with our pre-existing convention, where the `bar` module is actually a property of the `foo` object.  IOW, the desired *name* `foo.bar` actually reflects the status of `bar` as a property of `foo`.)

(Of course, `foo`, `bar`, and all the code below, are only toy examples.)

The contents of `js/main.js` are:

```
requirejs.config({
  baseUrl: 'js/lib',
  packages: ['foo'],
  paths: { ext: '../ext' }
});

requirejs(['foo', 'foo/bar'],
  function(foo, bar) {
    debugger;
  }
);
```

The call to `define` in `foo/bar.js` is this:

```
define('foo/bar', ['foo'], function (foo) { return foo.bar = {} });
```

If I change the first argument in `js/foo/bar.js`'s `define` call to `'foo.bar'`, the code still runs, but now the function in `js/main.js` gets `undefined` as its second argument.  (I can still access `bar` via `foo.bar`, of course, since the `foo/bar.js` file was executed as before.)

---

Here's a fuller run-down of what I have so far:

directory structure:

```
/.
|-- index.html
`-- js
    |-- ext
    |   `-- require.js
    |-- lib
    |   `-- foo
    |       |-- bar.js
    |       `-- main.js
    `-- main.js
```

HTML:

```
<script data-main="js/main.js" src="js/ext/require.js"></script>
```

./js/main.js

```
requirejs.config({
  baseUrl: 'js/lib',
  packages: ['foo'],
  paths: { ext: '../ext' }
});

requirejs(['foo', 'foo/bar'],
  function(foo, bar) {
    debugger;
  }
);
```

./js/foo/main.js

```
define(function () { return {} });
```

./js/foo/bar.js

```
define('foo/bar', ['foo'], function (foo) { return foo.bar = {} });
```